# How to implement ASN1 decoding in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, asn.1

I need to decode ASN1 strings from a complex sequence but I just cannot figure out how this whole thing works. I'd like to do something like

```
decoder = ASN1Library.initWithSequence(sequenceString);
ParseObject obj = decoder.decodeString(asn1String);
```

I have tried a few libraries but none allowed me to do what I want, or I was not able to understand how they work. I guess I need to implement a parser myself.

Can anybody explain how to do so?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Such requests are off topic here.

Comment: @GhostCat you're totally right, I'm sorry I did not put much effort into writing down a fine question. I also edited the original question.

Comment: This is better, not perfect, but better ;-) ... for a "perfect" question, you would outline the things you wanted and that these libraries did not provide. But at least for me, the question is "good enough" now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's what I found.
I am using `com.objsys.asn1j.runtime` library; I need to implement the whole sequence in Java classes, and make each class extend `Asn1Seq`, `Asn1Integer` or other super classes from the library.
In each class which extends Asn1Seq (ie. all Sequence-like classes) I need to override the `decode` method and in the body I have to call `decode` again on every attribute of the class.

Quick sample (both `Type1` and `Type2` extend `Asn1Integer`):

```
class SeqData extends Asn1Seq {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 55L;

  Type1 attribute1;
  Type2 attribute2;

@Override
public int getElementCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public String getElementName(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0) {
    case 0:
        return "attribute1";
    case 1:
        return "attribute2";
    }
    return "";
}

@Override
public Object getElementValue(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0) {
    case 0:
        return attribute1;
    case 1:
        return attribute2;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void decode(Asn1PerDecodeBuffer arg0) throws Asn1Exception, IOException {

    attribute1 = new Type1();
    attribute1.decode(arg0, 1L, 62L);

    attribute2 = new Type2();
    attribute2.decode(arg0, 1L, 62L);
}
```